# Unable to call function from a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I need to call a function from a make target,  this function would be called multiple time ,

```
define generate_file
if [ "${RQM_SETUP}" = "ci" ]; then
    echo "$1" > $(2).txt
else
    echo "It is Not Setup";
fi
endef
all:
        $(call generate_file,John Doe,101)
        $(call generate_file,Peter Pan,102)
```

right now i am stuck at this Error:

```
bash-5.0# make
if [ "" = "ci" ]; then
/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "fi")
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is multiple line, which will try to execute as separate shell invocations. This will fail as any single line is not syntactically correct on its own. You can make it work by setting it up in a single line, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
define generate_file
if [ "${RQM_SETUP}" = "ci" ]; then \
    echo "$1" > $(2).txt; \
else \
    echo "It is Not Setup"; \
fi
endef
all:
        $(call generate_file,John Doe,101)
        $(call generate_file,Peter Pan,102)
```

Output:

```
$ make
if [ "" = "ci" ]; then echo "John Doe" > 101.txt; else echo "It is Not Setup"; fi
It is Not Setup
if [ "" = "ci" ]; then echo "Peter Pan" > 102.txt; else echo "It is Not Setup"; fi
It is Not Setup
```

Comment: hey @raspy thank for clearing that up, now the above code works,, so tried implementing it with actual stuff which i want to do,, and in the when RQM_SETUP=ci is passed , it works as expected , but fails for the else part,

Comment: @MohammedAli Please don't do that. raspy answered your original question. If you have a *new* problem as a result, that should be a new question.